# Неправильный строковой калькулятор

Tags: php

Есть функция, которая считает число из строки.
Проверял при помощи var_dump массив, где хранятся числа
и массив где хранятся операторы, все на месте!

Но почему данная функция выводит -23, вместо 13.
Как решить данную проблему?

```js
function calc($value){
  
  $str_length = strlen($value);
  $str_array = [];
  $check_operators = ["+", "-", "*", "/"];
 
 
  for($a = 0; $a < $str_length; $a++){
  $str_array[] = $value[$a];
  }
 
 
  $final_array =[];
  $final_operator = [];
  $token = "";
  
  foreach($str_array as $items){    
    
    if ($items >= '0' && $items <= '9') {
    $token .= $items;
    } 
    else{
    array_push($final_array, $token);
    $token = '';
    }
    
    if(in_array($items, $check_operators)){ 
    $final_operator[] = $items; 
    }         
 
  }  
 
 
array_push($final_array, $token); 
 
  
 foreach($final_operator as $items){           
        
    $result = match($items){   
      "+" => function($b, $a, $calc_array):array{   
       array_push($calc_array, $a + $b);  
       return $calc_array;
       },  
   
       "-" => function($b, $a, $calc_array):array{   
       array_push($calc_array, $a - $b);  
       return $calc_array;
       },  
    
      "*" => function($b, $a, $calc_array):array{   
      array_push($calc_array, $a * $b);  
      return $calc_array;
      },  
    
      "/" => function($b, $a, $calc_array):array{   
      array_push($calc_array, $a / $b);  
      return $calc_array;
      },
    }; 
    
  $final_array = $result(array_pop($final_array), array_pop($final_array), $final_array);         
  }
 
 
return array_pop($final_array);
}
 
 
echo calc("5+5+5+2+2+2+2-10")."<br>"; //-23 че за бред?
```

Comment: `array_pop` забирает **последний** элемент из массива. Если вы с учётом этого факта внимательно проанализируете, как выполняется код и как в процессе меняется содержимое массива `$final_array`, то сможете разобраться, как посчиталось это самое -23

Comment: Логика кривая.. `$final_array = $result(array_pop($final_array), array_pop($final_array), $final_array);` - берёте последний и предпоследний элты а $final_operator содержит изначальный  порядок (array_shift будет брать первый и удалять). Но, это всё бесполезно и не уместно

Comment: Самое простое - выполнять операцию с 0 и 1 эл-том - в 0 или 1 записывать итог операции, а тот, в который не записывали - удалять... Условно, как-то так: `foreach ($final_operator as $operation) { $result = match($operation) { "+" => $final_array[0] + $final_array[1], "-" => $final_array[0] - $final_array[1], "*" => $final_array[0] * $final_array[1], "/" => $final_array[0] / $final_array[1] }; $final_array[1] = $result; array_shift($final_array); }`

Comment: @InDevX, но в моем коде нет array_shift

Comment: Ну да.. У Вас не нужный array_pop